# as3 converting video to byteArray

Tags: actionscript-3, file, video, path, arrays

i am attempting to upload a video to facebook using the as3 api(`FacebookMobile.uploadVideo`) which accepts a video as either  `fieleReferance` or `byteArray`. a followed the example @ http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d54.html for creating the `byteArray` i ma getting a 2058 error when uncompressing the byte array (this may be because i dident compress it but neither did adobe in the example).
if i comment this bit out i am getting  an `#353 You must select a video file to upload` error from Facebook.
Byte Array Code:

```
public function UICompleteHandler(event:MediaEvent):void
{
    trace("Welcome back from the camera");
    var media:MediaPromise = event.data;
    trace("file info "+media.file.url  + " - " + media.relativePath + " - " + media.mediaType);
    filePath = media.file.url;
    trace("Object encoding is: " + inBytes.objectEncoding + "\n\n" + "order file: \n\n");
    readFileIntoByteArray(filePath, inBytes); 
    trace("length 1:   "+inBytes.length);
    trace("position 1: "+inBytes.position);
    inBytes.position = 0; // reset position to beginning 

    //inBytes.uncompress(CompressionAlgorithm.DEFLATE); 

    trace("position 2:  "+inBytes.position);
    inBytes.position = 0;    //reset position to beginning 
}
private function readFileIntoByteArray(fileName:String, data:ByteArray):void 
{ 
     var inFile:File = new File(fileName);
     trace ("file to byte array  "+  inFile.url);
     trace ("file name var : "+fileName);

     inStream.open(inFile , FileMode.READ);
     inStream.readBytes(data); 
     inStream.close(); 
}
```

Handle Upload Code:

```
public function handleUpload(ev:TouchEvent)
{
    trace ("posting to facebook - FileName: "+  accessCamera.fileName + " - FilePath: " + accessCamera.filePath);
    var params:Object ={  
        title:'test upload on FB api',
        description:'test upload on FB api',
        fileName: accessCamera.fileName,
        video: accessCamera.inBytes
    }

    trace ("params.video = "+params.video);

    FacebookMobile.uploadVideo('me/videos', onComplete, params);
}

private function onComplete( result:Object, fail:Object ):void {
    trace("facebook post onComplete called" );
    if (result)
    {
        //result.id is id of post that was just posted
        trace ("great");
    }
    else if (fail)
    {
        trace("post Failed");  
        trace('code: '+fail.error.code); 
        trace('message: '+fail.error.message);
        trace('type: '+fail.error.type); 
    }
}
```

when i trace out the `params.video` i get a load of random characters. the problem seems to be facebook dosnt appear to see the `bytearray`(if i even success fully created it) as a video.

Comment: The adobe example does decompress when writing the bytes. Try decompress when writing and see if the uncompressing is still giving problems. Also, update your question to include the trace of the params.video before you try to upload.

Comment: you mean put it in the `readFileIntoByteArray` method? when i trace out `params.video` i get a load of random characters in the output pannel. sorry for late reply i was parted from my laptop for a day.

Comment: i also tried moving the `uncompress` to no avail